# Could further oil drilling remove an insulation layer of the Earth cores heat?

Tags: temperature, drilling

Putting aside burning fossil fuels, what are the consequences of another 100 years of drilling deeper and deeper to extract oil reserves globally?

Would this significant extraction remove an insulation layer of the core's heat enabling for heat to rise more freely towards the crust?  How much would this effect the earth's ground temperature?

Comment: Hello Chris, welcome to Stack Exchange!  Indeed it does appear this question will probably get closed, as there's that question Camilo linked that's basically the same one (if you feel there are key differences between your question and his, feel free to point that out, and perhaps we can focus on those items in your question).  Nothing to fret about, it happens, it's just a way to keep things organized/easier to find/central.  Pay good attention when typing up your question to verify your question it's similar to a previous question (it offers potential matches you can check).

Comment: But nothing to stress over for this one being closed.  It was still an interesting/different question, and we hope you come here and try to get insight if you have any other constructive questions :-)

Answer (score 1):

I think your basic assumption is incorrect. Removing oil and the 80 to 90% water associated with it would reduce the thermal conductivity of the rock formations. It removes these liquids which aid thermal conductivity across the myriad of very tiny pores that contained the liquids. In the US regulations have the affect of the water being pumped back into the ground , not necessarily into the same formation. Outside the US that is not generally the case. Without doing any arithmetic, this appears to be a minuscule affect on earth temperature.....Thinking about it a little , you could likely make a better case on the basis  of the heat in the produced fluids ( water ,oil, gas): I know difficult wells go into formations that are 400 F+ , overall average the average temperature of production is likely between 200 and 300 F. No doubt SPE has real data but I am no longer a member.